# Storing form data using html & php

Tags: php, html, forms

I've got a form with 50 questions.  After the user has filled in the form, I want to take them to another page to first cancel / confirm that they are finished with the form.  My question is if they select cancel, how do I put back all the fields that has been answered in the form?

**EDITED**

I've edited my question to show my code because I'm strugling:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid' ORDER BY RAND()";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
echo "<form method='post' action='....'>";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $test_name=$row1['test_name'];
    $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
    $q_type=$row1['q_type'];
    $question=$row1['question'];
    $option1=$row1['option1'];
    $option2=$row1['option2'];
    $option3=$row1['option3'];

echo "$question";

if ($q_type != 'mr') {
if($option1!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='A'>$option1<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }

if($option2!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='B'>$option2<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }

if($option3!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='C'>$option3<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }

} else { // else if not <> mr

if($option1!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='A'>$option1<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
if($option2!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='B'>$option2<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
if($option3!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='C'>$option3<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
} //end else if q_type <> mr
echo "<BR>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "</p>";
} //end while row1
echo "<input type='submit' value='Finish'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Cancel button a Submit and let it post back to the original questionnaire. In there, you can do like this:

```
<input type="text" name="q1" value="<?=isset($_POST['q1']) ? $_POST['q1'] : '';?>" />
```

Or:

```
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" <?=isset($_POST['q2']) && $_POST['q2'] == 'A' ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?>" />
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="B" <?=isset($_POST['q2']) && $_POST['q2'] == 'B' ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?>" />
```

Same goes for `option` elements inside a `select` (selected="selected").

Comment: Can you please be so kind and have a look at my edited question

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any additional question I can answer?

Comment: My apologies, I am trying to implement your code on my original but I can't get it to work, it looks like this `echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='A'=isset($_POST['question[$q_nr]']) && $_POST['question[$q_nr]'] == 'A' ? 'checked='checked'' : '';' />";`

Comment: "On servers with shorthand support enabled you can start a scripting block with <? and end with ?>.

For maximum compatibility, we recommend that you use the standard form (<?php) rather than the shorthand form."

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array to the confirmation page, and if they hit cancel, pass the array back to the page, and fill in the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be adding:

```
<INPUT type=button value="Cancel" onClick="history.back();">
```

When you go back, the form would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$_REQUEST['Answer']` in **value** tag of form.

Comment: Hi Justin is there is a problem with my comments